# Colour transfer to resin

Tags: resin, color

Is it possible to perform a colour transfer from paper/transparency film to printed resin?

From what I understand there is some sort of transfer process for resin, but I don't quite understand if this works for 3D printed resins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the second video, the resin is used to coat a surface. The resin is clear, or appropriately tinted to provide for a visually pleasing background to the transfer. The transparency is printed on an inkjet printer which embeds the ink into a surface designed to accept the ink, rather than allowing it to bead up, as in the first video.

When the transparency is applied to the wet resin surface and the resin is allowed to cure, the specially formulated transparency surface is transferred to the resin surface, akin to gluing the entire image, using the backing of the transparency "paper" as the carrier. Once cured, the backing peels off, leaving the image.

There is no analogy to resin 3D printing. If you 3D print a resin model that has a suitable flat surface, you could certainly apply the same types of resin shown in the video and duplicate that process. If the surface was not flat, you'll have irregularities in the transparency which will prevent the image from being transferred.

I can't envision how the inkjet image could be transferred during the 3D resin printing process, as the transparency film would interfere with the bonding of the resin to the build plate or the vat surface.